# What is a Flat Object?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, object, jdbc

What does a Flat Object mean in the Pole Position Client Server Model benchmarks (see picture below)?

[image]

I am trying to figure out which benchmarks I should look at for a small and simple web application... should I be looking at the Flatobject benchmarks? Benchmarks doc found at http://polepos.sourceforge.net/results/PolePositionClientServer.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the other tests of the benchmark test

- a complex object graph
- nested lists
- objects with a 5 level inheritance structure

I would say that a flat object is an object with no relation to any other entity/table, and which directly extends `java.lang.Object`.